# Why do I get "uninitialized constant ApplicationController::SessionsHelper (NameError)"?

Tags: ruby

I'm doing Michael Hart's tutorial and I get the error:

```
rails_projects/sample_app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:3:in `<class:ApplicationController>': uninitialized constant ApplicationController::SessionsHelper (NameError)
```

Here is my application_controller.rb file:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper

  # Force signout to prevent CSRF attacks
  def handle_unverified_request
    sign_out
    super
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You should have a file in app/helpers named "sessions_helper.rb".  Inside of that you should at least have code like:

```
module SessionsHelper
end
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm getting the error:  undefined method `subject' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Comment: Can you accept this answer and ask your new question separately?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you got the answer yet, but I was able to comment the sessionhelper line out and get mine to work. I don't know if this has any far-reaching ramifications, but it help me circumvent the issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you define `SessionHelper`? If it's at the top level module, try this:

```
include ::SessionHelper
```

Answer (score 0):

Change  include SessionsHelper  to include SessionHelper
remove **S**

Comment: In case someone comes from google - This answer is completly wrong. It is supposed to be _include SessionsHelper_

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Make sure you have run the migration once deployed to heroku:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```